# Highlight hashtags and @usernames and make cliackable in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am building where I want to highlight text that starts with "@" and "#" and also make them clickable in flutter but cant seem to find any link or package that does it. The only able to get is the hashtag flutter package [hashtagtext](https://pub.dev/packages/hashtagtext/example)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `Elevated Button`, `OutlinedButton`, `TextButton`, or `GestureDetector`?

Example:

```
OutlinedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text('@Test'),),
ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text('@Test'),),
TextButton(onPressed: () {}, child: Text('@Test'),),
GestureDetector(onTap: () {}, child: Text('@Test'),),
```

Comment: Can you show an example?

Answer (score 0):

you can use Text.rich:

```
        Text.rich(
          TextSpan(
            text: 'Bla bla bla ',
            style: const TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontSize: 30,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
            children: <InlineSpan>[
              WidgetSpan(
                child: TextButton(
                  onPressed: () { print('@blablabla'); }, 
                  child: Text('@blablabla'),
                ),
              ),
              const TextSpan(
                text: 'bla bla bla.',
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```